# Rails 4 Upgrade - ActionController::UrlGenerationError - No route matches

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, upgrade, rspec2, rspec-rails

I am trying to port my application from Rails 3.2.x to Rails 4.0.4. All the gems have been made compatible and I am in the phase of fixing failing tests.

I have this weird test failure.

My `routes.rb`

```
resources :my_reports, only: [:index] do
  collection do
    get "/report/:filename", to: :show, prefix: "pri/excl/rep", as: :show
  end
end
```

My spec which **has been passing in Rails 3.2.x** and now failing after update to 4.0.4

```
describe MyReportsController do
  describe "#show" do
    def make_request
      get :show, prefix: 'some/place', filename: 'foo', format: 'doc'
    end

    it "makes a simple request" do
      make_request
    end
  end
end
```

I am getting the following error

```
Failure/Error: get :show, prefix: 'some/place', filename: 'foo', format: 'doc'
     ActionController::UrlGenerationError:
       No route matches {:action=>"show", :controller=>"my_reports", 
        :filename=>"foo", :format=>"doc", :prefix=>"some/place"}
```

I am stuck at this point, hints are welcome. I am using rspec and rspec-rails versions 2.14.1.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Passing a dummy :id in the test fixed the issue for me although I would not like it, tests pass.

```
get :show, id: "", prefix: 'some/place', filename: 'foo', format: 'doc'
```

Refer to state of rails releases [here](http://tech.bragboy.com/2016/09/state-of-rails-releases.html).

Answer (score 0):

You're describing the `show` method but your route is only available for the `index` one. Maybe it's a beginning of solution.

Comment: No, I checked it already. Even included show in the resources, but that should ideally have no impact as I have explicitly using `:as`

Comment: Have you tried directly `get :show, prefix: ...` without nested method ?